# Changing color of button dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the color of button as soon as me changes the hex in input box.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hex").on('change', function(){  
    var hex = $("#hex").val();
    $("#btn").css({"background-color":hex});
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="hex" />
<input type="button" id="btn" />
```

But no it doesn't work is there anything that could be done with more precision?

Comment: Change event fired after input blur, you should use it along with `keydown` or `keyup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$('#hex').on('input')` event like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hex").on('input', function(){

        var hex = $("#hex").val();
        $("#btn").css({"background-color":hex});
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="hex" placeholder="red" />

<input type="button" id="btn" />
```

> Try to type color name inside text input and see the button color changes!